# Not using templates Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am having a hard time finding anything on the topic. What if I wanted to use a controller to simply render a static page such as `about.php`? When I try the following I get a template not found error.

```
public function aboutAction()
{
    return $this->render('FooBundle:Default:about.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render the page without creating a controller:

```
foo_about:
    path: /about
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'FooBundle:Default:about.html.php'
```

The `about.html.php` must be located under `Resources/views/Default/` directory of the `FooBundle`.

See [How to render a Template without a custom Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't really answer the question, I want to use a controller to decide what page to render and prepare a response. I can't exactly `prepare` a response if I'm not using a controller.

Comment: Good, but you didn't mentioned it. You said static page, and for me a static page must not prepared. But take notice to the last sentence, where template files must be located.