# How to render a static page without a controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am starting to learn Symfony and I am confused on exactly where to place the example YAML code shown on this page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Specifically,  where does this code live:

```
acme_privacy:
    path: /privacy
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    static/privacy.html.twig
```

The closest thing I can find when searching for an answer is this post: [Not using templates Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098054/not-using-templates-symfony-2/19098291#19098291).  However, it doesn't clarify where to place this code either.

Thanks

**Edit: My app/config/routing.yml file**

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

I added this to the end of the file and it worked!

```
testing_privacy:
    path: /privacy
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    static/privacy.html.twig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably in `app/config/routing.yml`

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I had looked in that file but the existing code in there looked different from the example so it threw me off.

Comment: Could I have a look to your routing.yml?